# Glass renders badly, but it's fine in viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, glass

For some reason my glass looks the way i want it to with cycles in the viewport, but when i render it, it darkens, and looks bad (see attached).

I'm using Blender 2.79 and the Principled BDSF shader.

I've upped the transparency and bounces in the render settings, nothing happened.

Any help, greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Blend File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ctto4f198ez50dh/jar.blend?dl=0

[image: Difference in glass material: sample vs render]

Comment: It would help to get the blend file, for example via [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). In your render settings, there do not appear to  be any problems. Check if you have an object disabled in the viewport, but enabled for rendering.

Comment: Thank you! i did have a solidify modifier disabled in viewport, but turned on for render. i spaced out on that...